# Javascript DOM удаление всех дочерних узлов

Tags: javascript

Задача имеет вид:

> Создайте страницу с кнопкой, при нажатии на кнопке на странице должен создаваться параграф с произвольним текстом. После создания 10 параграфов все они должны быть удалены.

У меня заминка как после создания 10 параграфов их удалить?!

```js
function createNewPar() {
  var list = document.getElementById("test");

  var item = document.createElement("p");
  item.innerHTML = "NEW ITEM";

  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add Par" onclick="createNewPar()" />
```

Comment: jQuery есть на сайте? Или какой другой JS framework? Или Вы пытаетесь это реализовать стандартными средствами javascript?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения задачи? Что именно не получилось? Решение учебных задач за учащихся очень не приветствуется на этом сайте.

Comment: на чистом js. проблема не знаю, как стереть сразу 10 параграфов

Comment: разве document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "" не прокатит?

Comment: пробывал, но не так не получилось...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует несколько способов удаления дочерних узлов. Например, вы можете вручную обойти все дочерние узлы и удалить их:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
}
```

Детального решения именно вашей учебной задачи приводить не буду, поскольку вы должны решить ее сами. На то она и **учебная**.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @user191427, если я правильно ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как "верный".

Answer (score 1):

Современный способ в 2022 - использование `replaceChildren()` без параметров:

```
const list = document.getElementById("test");
list.replaceChildren();
```

[Офф. документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren#emptying_a_node)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать innerHTML:

```
const myContainer = document.getElementById("test");
myContainer.innerHTML = '';
```